# Android: how to configure the textView outline black border in xml layout properly

Tags: android, layout, outline

How can I add a black and solid outline border to a textView.
I tried this code:

```xml
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/faqTitle"
    style="@style/viewParent.headerText.HomeCardTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:shadowColor="@color/colorRed"
    android:shadowRadius="15"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:text="TEST" />
```

The problem is that after updating showRadius, the outline is not solid.
I don't want to use an external library. Only uses of XML attributes.
Please take a look at the attached images.

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra8T2.png)

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQDu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For outline to characters you can use below code

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textColor="#FFC107"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In .java file put these lines to give border to TextView characters

```java
TextView textViewShadow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test1);
textViewShadow.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(5);
textViewShadow.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: This works thank you so much. There is a way to do it only on the xml layout? without the java code?

Comment: Most welcome
I will try with xml layout if found any solution I will update you